# Obj-C and SpriteKit - Changing a sprite value that is created randomly

Tags: objective-c, random, sprite-kit, game-physics, sprite

I'm making a game using SpriteKit and Objective-C.

I have four different texture drops (Blue, Green, Orange and Red) that falls down on screen randomly.

In my ANBDropNode class I have this method:

```
+(instancetype)dropOfType:(ANBDropType)type {

    ANBDropsNode *drop;

    if (type == ANBDropTypeBlue) {
        drop = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bluedrop"];
    } else if (type == ANBDropTypeGreen) {
        drop = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"greendrop"];
    } else if (type == ANBDropTypeOrange) {
        drop = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"orangedrop"];
    } else if (type == ANBDropTypeRed){
        drop = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"reddrop"];
    }

    [drop setupPhysicsBody];
    return drop;
}
```

And in my GamePlayScene these two:

```
    -(void)addDrops {

        NSUInteger randomDrop = [ANBUtil randomWithMin:0 max:4];

        self.drop = [ANBDropsNode dropOfType:randomDrop];

        float y = self.frame.size.height + self.drop.size.height;
        float x = [ANBUtil randomWithMin:10 + self.drop.size.width
                                     max:self.frame.size.width - self.drop.size.width - 10];
        self.drop.position = CGPointMake(x, y);

        [self addChild:self.drop];
    }

    -(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

        if (self.lastUpdateTimeInterval) {
            self.timeSinceDropAdded += currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
        }

        if (self.timeSinceDropAdded > 1) {
            [self addDrops];
            self.timeSinceDropAdded = 0;
        }

        self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;

}
```

The question is (and it may sound a little dumber, I know): before the drop hits the ground it has already changed it value. If ANBDropNode *drop is a bluedrop, before it hits the ground the method randomly create another drop and change it value for greendrop, for example. But I don't want this behavior. I want the drop to continue with its value until it reaches the ground so I can detect its color in my didBeginContact method.

Comment: I'm not following what youre trying to do.  Maybe simplify the question a little?

Comment: Ok, let me try: how can I Keep *drop with de same value until it reaches the ground so I can detect a collision based on its color in my didBeginContact method? If the drop has the same color as the ground the game continues. If it's different, gameover.

Comment: self.drop is a reference to a single object, if you need to keep track of all drops, use an array instead

Comment: Sorry @LearnCocos2D, but I'm new to programming. Can you explain your point? Do you think that I have to use an array in my +(instancetype)dropOfType method or in my -(void)addDrops? Or neither? Tnanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry in advance for any english mistakes, as I'm not an native english speaker.

From your question I understand that the reason you are keeping a reference to the drop (`self.drop`) is to check what is its colour when it hits the ground.
So you could just delete that, and create a new `SKSpriteNode` object each time, instead of just changing the reference of the current property.
If you have any other reason for keeping a reference to that drop, just still keep a reference.
Note that doing any of the above, will not affect the code below.

I think that you were in the right direction (when asking about `didBeginContact`) but took the wrong approach/mindset, since there is no need to keep a reference when using `didBeginContact`, because you can get the nodes in contact from this method.

Anyway, here is the code + explanations

```
// MyScene.m  

// First, conform to SKPhysicsContactDelegate, so you can get didBeginContact 'calls'
@interface MyScene () <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>  
@end  

@implementation MyScene  

// Now add the following constant, that you'll use as the physics body category bit masks  
static const uint32_t groundCategory = 0x01 << 0;  
static const uint32_t dropsCategory  = 0x01 << 1;  

// Somewhere in your initialisation, set yourself to be the physicsWorld  
// contact delegate, so you'll receive the didBeginContact 'calls',  
// And also call setupGround method, that we will create in here as well
-(id)initSceneWithSize:(CGSize)size {  
    ...
    ...
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;  
    [self setupGround];  
    ...  
}  

// Here we will create the ground node, so we can detect when a drop  
// Hits the ground.  
// The reason that, in the below code, I am setting just the ground,  
// and not the whole borders of the screen, is because the drops  
// are added above the screen 'borders', and if we would make  
// a 'frame' node, and not a 'ground' node, we will also receive  
// contact delegate calls, when the nodes first enter the scene  
// and hits the top 'border' of the frame
-(void)setupGround {  
    SKNode *groundNode     = [SKNode node];  
    groundNode.strokeColor = [SKColor clearColor];  
    groundNode.fillColor   = [SKColor clearColor];  
    // Not sure if the above two are mandatory, but better be safe than sorry...  

    // Here we set the physics body to start at the bottom left edge of the screen  
    // and be the width of the screen, and the size of 1 points  
    // Then, we also set its category bit mask
    CGRect groundRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, 1);
    groundNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:groundRect];  
    groundNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = groundCategory;  

    [self addChild:groundNode];  
}  

// Next we will modify your current method of creating drops, to also have  
// their name property to holds the corresponding colour name  
+(instancetype)dropOfType:(ANBDropType)type {

    ANBDropsNode *drop;

    if (type == ANBDropTypeBlue) {
        drop = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bluedrop"];
        drop.name = @"Blue";
    } else if (type == ANBDropTypeGreen) {
        drop = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"greendrop"];
        drop.name = @"Green";
    } else if (type == ANBDropTypeOrange) {
        drop = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"orangedrop"];
        drop.name = @"Orange";
    } else if (type == ANBDropTypeRed){
        drop = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"reddrop"];
        drop.name = @"Red";
    }

    [drop setupPhysicsBody];
    return drop;
}  

// In your setupPhysicsBody method of the drop, add the following to define  
// the drop's bit mask, contact test, and collision.  
// Make sure you are adding them AFTER setting the physics body, and not before.  
// Since you revealed no code regarding this method, I will assume 'self' is  
// referring to the drop, since you call this method on the drop.
-(void) setupPhysicsBody {  
    ...  
    ...  
    ...  
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask    = dropsCategory;  
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory;  
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask   = 0;  
    // The above code sets the drop category bit mask, sets its contactTestBitMask  
    // to be of the groundCategory, so whenever an object with drop category, will  
    // 'touch' and object with groundCategory, our didBeginContact delegate will  
    // get called.  
    // Also, we've set the collision bit mask to be 0, since we only want to  
    // be notified when a contact begins, but we don't actually want them both to  
    // 'collide', and therefore, have the drops 'lying' on the ground.  
    ...  
    ...  
    ...  
}  

// Now we can set the didBeginContact: delegate method.  
// Note that, as the name of the method suggests, this method gets called when a  
// Contact is began, meaning, the drop is still visible on screen.  
// If you would like to do whatever you want to do, when the drop leaves the screen,  
// just call the didEndContact: delegate method  
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {  
    // SKPhysicsContact have two properties, bodyA and bodyB, which represents  
    // the two nodes that contacted each other.  
    // Since there is no certain way to know which body will always be our drop,  
    // We will check the bodies category bit masks, to determine which is which  
    ANBDropsNode *drop = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? (ANBDropsNode *)contact.bodyB.node : (ANBDropsNode *)contact.bodyA.node;  
    // In the above we are checking the category bit masks,  
    // Note that we set groundCategory to be 1, and dropsCategory to be 2,  
    // So we are checking which is higher.  
    // If bodyA bit mask is lower than bodyB bit mask, that means the bodyA is  
    // the ground, and bodyB is the drop, so we set the drop to be bodyB's node  
    // Else, we set it to be bodyA's node.  

    // Now you can easily get the drop colour from the name property we've set in  
    // the beginning. you can do some sort of if-else statement, that check  
    // 'if isEqualToString'. Here I just NSLog the colour  
    NSLog(@"%@", drop.name);

}
```

Good luck mate.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply associate a property with the ANBDropsNode class which can be set when the drop is instantiated.

In the ANBDropsNode.h file,

```
@interface ANBDropsNode

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *dropColor; //This property will hold the value associated with the color.
```

Then in the dropOfType class method:

```
+(instancetype)dropOfType:(ANBDropType)type {

    NSString *strDropColor;

    if (type == ANBDropTypeBlue) {
        strDropColor = @"bluedrop";
    } else if (type == ANBDropTypeGreen) {
        strDropColor = @"greendrop";
    } else if (type == ANBDropTypeOrange) {
        strDropColor = @"orangedrop";
    } else if (type == ANBDropTypeRed){
        strDropColor = @"reddrop";
    }

    ANBDropsNode *drop = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:strDropColor];
    drop.dropColor = strDropColor;

    [drop setupPhysicsBody];
    return drop;
}
```

Now, in your collision detection delegate method, you can find out the color of the node by simply referring the `dropColor` property.